# Clean way to assign value unless empty

Tags: ruby

I often need to assign a variable, if the source value is set. So far I have done it like this:

```
filters[:red] = params[:search][:red] unless params[:search][:red].nil?
```

This works but looks a bit clumsy. There must be a more DRY way of getting this result.

Any suggestions?

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell.

Comment: do you have sample data for params[:search]?  Certain clever solutions depend upon what's in there.  Specifically, do nils represent items that are in the hash but with nil values, or do they represent items that are not in the hash at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself doing a lot of these you could write a little helper method:

```
def set_unless_nil(hsh, key, val)
  hsh[key] = val unless val.nil?
end
```

and then:

```
set_unless_nil filters, :red, params[:search][:red]
```

And if the key in the source and destination hashes is frequently the same you could write:

```
def copy_key_unless_nil(src_hash, key, dest_hash)
  dest_hash[key] = src_hash[key] unless src_hash[key].nil?
end
```

and then:

```
copy_key_unless_nil params[:search], :red, filters
```

Alternatively you could just set the values into the Hash anyway and then tidy the hash at the end to remove all the keys with a nil value:

```
filters.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already pretty good, but it could be a little dry-er

```
red=params[:search][:red]
filters[:red]=red if red
```

it looks a little bit neater this way and will still work as you intend. Always remember you can rewrite:

```
unless x.nil?
```

as:

```
if x
```

they will evaluate the same, but the latter is slightly more ambiguous and cleaner

Comment: `unless x.nil?` and `if x` are not equivalent if `x == false`

Answer (score 0):

If `params[:search][:red]` can only be nil because it is not in the hash, I'd use `params[:search].has_key?(:red)` so that a casual reader can understand what the situation is better.

Answer (score 0):

If params[:search][:red] can only be nil because it is not in the hash, and assuming you want to copy everything in params[:search] to filters, then:

```
filters.merge!(params[:search])
```